# What's the difference between faries and pixies?

Tags: fantasy-genre, fairy

I am struggling to find a **difference**? I honestly do not know a difference, I have tried all kinds of folklore books. Tell me a difference?

Comment: To answer this question, it really needs to be localized -- Are you talking in a specific fictional universe?  Some have them as the same thing with a different name.  Some have them as the same SPECIES, but different subgroup.  Some have them as unrelated, but similar.  Often 'Fairy' is a category (read as 'Fey') and Pixies are a specific kind.  RL folklore is not terribly consistent, either, but a specific fictional universe could render the question a lot more answerable.

Comment: Also, the original celtic Faeries were not exactly the fluffy and nice like whatsherface from Peter Pan.

Comment: ...who says there _is_ a difference?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia-sourced (via Askville@Amazon))

> A fairy (sometimes seen as faery, faerie, or even fae; collectively wee folk, good folk, people of peace or many other euphemisms) is a spirit or supernatural being that is found in the legends, folklore, and mythology. The term came into use in the folklore of Western Europe in the medieval era; it has be used to translate the terms of many different cultures, referring to beings similar to (though often with distinct differences) the Western European fairy (see List of beings referred to as fairies). Even in the folkore that uses the term, there are many definitions of what constitutes a fairy, sometimes describing any magical creature, like a goblin or gnome, and at other times to describe a specific type of creature, distinct from such creatures as hobgoblins.
>
> Pixies or Piskies as they are known in Cornwall are mythical creatures of English folklore, considered to be particularly concentrated in the areas around Devon and Cornwall, suggesting some Celtic origin for the belief and name. In regional dialect, these mischievous little folk are sometimes referred to as piskies/piskeys or the little people. They are usually depicted as wingless, with pointed ears, and often wearing a green outfit and pointed hat. Sometimes their eyes are described as being pointed upwards at the temple ends.

Moreover, Pixies Wiki says:

> In modern use, the term can be synonymous with fairies or sprites. However, in folklore there is a traditional enmity, and even war between the two races (src: *A Peep at the Pixies; or Legends of he West, Bay A.E., 1853*)

Answer (score 1):

Pixies are usually mischievous beings, and cause damage to others, whereas fairies can be good or evil. Fairies have magical powers, whereas pixies usually lack magic, however this is not the case in all fictional universes. Pixies are always visible and can interact with hunmans, whereas fairies can choose to be visible or invisible. In some series, only fairies or pixies exist. For instance, in the *Harry Potter* series, only pixies exist.